# OSX upgrade => brew update

Tags: macos, homebrew

A Macbook was upgrade from yosemite to Sierra to High-Sierra.  The feedback indicates that brew is configured for yosemite:

```
brew install members
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-portable-ruby/portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring portable-ruby-2.6.3_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/services).
```

What is the optimal (preferably simple) technique to ensure that brew is correctly configured for High-Sierra?

## UPDATE

I followed the instructions returned by `brew doctor`, which seemed to clear up many errors.   (thank you)

Additional:

`brew update`
Already up-to-date.

Users-Air:~ user$ `brew install members`

> Error: No available formula with the name "members"
> ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)... Error: No previously deleted formula found.
> ==> Searching for similarly named formulae... Error: No similarly named formulae found.
> ==> Searching taps...
> ==> Searching taps on GitHub... Error: No formulae found in taps.

Users-Air:~ user$ `members`

```
-bash: members: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brew doctor` is always your friend on healtchecking your homebrew installations.

[update]

I could not find `members` formula either.

```
$ brew search members
No formula or cask found for "members".
Open pull requests:
hugo 0.70.0 (new formula)  (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/57334)
```

Comment: Please elaborate?  Any specific suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Can you run `brew doctor` in your terminal and update the thread?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Thread updated: any comments or observations are appreciated.  I ran brew doctor an hour ago, but did not record the feedback, however, many errors were found & corrected.  A little cryptic: blindly following instructions is a little nerve racking

Comment: So it sounds like `members` formula does not exist?

Comment: I just did a cross-check , could not find it in the homebrew-core as well. Where did you find members formula reference?

Comment: I do not remember why I thought I could invoke `brew install members`   Apparently this is not possible.   Maybe it was wishful thinking after seeing it available for my Ubuntu box.   BTW, looking forward to NYC meet ups when C19 is vanquished!

Comment: yeah, missing the nyc tech meetups. :D stay safe!